# How can I mix a base64 encoded background image with crossbrowser gradients?

Tags: css, background, base64, gradient

I'm trying to get a background with multiple backgrounds to work. I was thinking of using a `base64` encoded image, and a gradient and I'm wondering how to combine both...

Here is what I have:

```
.el  {  
    background-color: #ebe5e5;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iV...10k of foo...CC);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ebe5e5), to(#e1dbdb));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #ebe5e5, #e1dbdb);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ebe5e5, #e1dbdb);
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(center top, #ebe5e5, #e1dbdb);
    background:         linear-gradient(center to bottom, #ebe5e5, #e1dbdb);
    }
```

I'm wondering if I need to specify both backgrounds together like `background1, background2`, but that would mean my base64 encoded images-string would have to be declaration multiple times and for that it's just too big.

**Question:**
Is there a way to use multiple CSS backgrounds with a gradient and a base64 encoded image WITHOUT having to specify the base64 image for every browser prefix?

Comment: Have you tried nesting your base64 image div within other divs that have the gradient?

Comment: Good idea. Will give it a try.